# Adding values to a template in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 22 genres in my movie page that I am designing in Wordpress and with some PHP. Basically rather than me typing out 22 different taxonomy pages e.g. `taxonomy-genre-action.php` to `taxonomy-genre-western.php` I am going to use a template `genre-template`.
But what I don't understand is how do I get the value/destination of a hyperlink to change two values on the `genre-template` page e.g.

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'movies',
        'orderby'           => 'name',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'tax_query'         => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'      => 'genre',
                'field'         => 'slug',
                'terms'         => 'action' // [CHANGE HERE]
            )
        )
    );

?>

<h2 style="color: white">action movies</h2> <!-- [CHANGE HERE] -->
```

Change the 'action' value to whatever hyperlink to the other 21 genres are.

```
<a href="/wordpress/genre/<?php echo $args[$termCount]; ?>"><?php echo $args[$termCount]; ?></a>
```

How would I add the `$args[$termcount]` value to the `genre-template.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to create a general archive page for your custom taxonomy (genre) terms, right?

I'll suggest you read, understand and practice [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) in depth.

If WordPress can't find `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php` then it'll fallback to `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php`. So, in your case, you can just create one archive file named `taxonomy-genre.php` and you'll be good to go.

Also, you don't even need to construct a `query` in the archive file. WordPress will know that it's an archive call and will prepare `query` for that `term` automatically.

Now, to get the current term's data, use [`get_queried_object();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) to your advantage. For example, to get the term name,

```
get_queried_object()->name;
```

Comment: geez I'm so rubbish @ this. <h2 style="color: white"><?php echo get_queried_object('name'); ?> movies</h2> didn't work and I lost now sorry

Comment: As the name suggests `get_queried_object()`, this returns an object and members of an object are accessed as `get_queried_object()->name;`

Comment: also you said I didn't need to create a query in the archive file, but then how will it list all the movies with that specific genre?

Comment: WP will identify that this is an archive loop/file and will generate the query automatically. Don't worry about that

Comment: for some stupid reason I cant get it to output the correct content. e.g.<?php $query = new WP_Query( ); ?>

    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

Comment: Just do this, `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?> <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

Comment: sorry I didn't let you know I figured it out, but thanks a lot m8